# Strange response from NSData fetching from JSON

Tags: iphone, json

Trying to fetch value from json, response string showing correct fetched data, but when NSData convert and put it in to NSDictionary, two values get interchanged.
Below is code tried.

```
 +(NSMutableDictionary *)seatMap:(NSDictionary *)seatId eventId:(NSDictionary *)eid
 {
 NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://met.co/api/seatmap/%@/%@",   [seatId valueForKey:@"sid"], [eid valueForKey:@"eid"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                [NSURL URLWithString:
                                 [urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                                  NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
//NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];

NSString *responseString = [MetApi sendRequest:request];
NSLog(@"response:%@", responseString);
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

//NSDictionary *results = [responseString JSONValue];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:results];
NSLog(@"dict in API-------------%@",dict);

return dict;
}
```

Above code giving this output

```
        1 = off;
        10 = off;
        2 = on;
        3 = on;
        4 = on;
        5 = on;
        6 = on;
        7 = on;
        8 = on;
        9 = on;
```

But it should

```
1: "off",
2: "on",
3: "on",
4: "on",
5: "on",
6: "on",
7: "on",
8: "on",
9: "on",
10: "off"
```

json file

```
{
row1: {
1: "on",
2: "on",
3: "on",
4: "on",
5: "on",
6: "on",
7: "on",
8: "on",
9: "on",
10: "on",
attr: {
total: "10",
type: "Gold"
}
},
row2: {
1: "off",
2: "on",
3: "on",
4: "on",
5: "on",
6: "on",
7: "on",
8: "on",
9: "on",
10: "off",
attr: {
total: "10",
type: "Gold"
}
}
}
}
```

Why this interchange of data happening. Please guide for the above, if anything not clear please ask.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got answer here sort NSDictionary.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913847/sort-nsdictionary-in-ascending-order/16915518?noredirect=1#16915518

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON contains only dictionaries and dictionaries do not maintain order. In other words, the order of elements when you print a dictionary is entirely implementation specific and may even be random.

If order is relevant, you have to use lists (e.g. `[1,2,3]`)

For example, you could use the following JSON

```
{ "rows":
  [ { "values":["on", "on", "on", "on", "on", "on", "on", "on", "on", "on"]
    , "attr": { "total": 10
              , "type": "Gold"
              }
    }
,   { "values":["off", "on", "on", "on", "on", "on", "on", "on", "on", "off"]
    , "attr": { "total": 10
              , "type": "Gold"
              }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you don't want to change your JSON and get the values, say of `row1` in order you could use the following snippet (not recommended, if order is important, use a list!):

```
/* expects `NSDictionary *dict` as defined in the code of your question. Code is untested but should give you the idea... */
NSInteger max = [dict[@"row1"][@"attr"][@"total"] intValue];

for (int i=1; i<= max; i++) {
    NSLog("value %ld = '%@'", i, dict[@"row1"][@"attr"][[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]]);
}
```

Comment: Ok, but isn't there any solution programmatically, that i can handle form  my code.

Comment: What's the problem? I guessed the problem is that the order is "1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9" and not "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: you are right, you guessed the problem right. But you suggested to change the json, i am just asking is there any way to handle this thing programmatically rather than changing json.

Comment: see the edit, maybe that covers what you want. Otherwise specify the problem. I still don't understand what you want to achieve and that's crucial to help you find the solution.

Comment: A drawback with the `NSDictionary` is that it does not maintain order for you. If you want it to be ordered, you'll have to do it yourself. Make a category for the best solution here.

Comment: @FarrukhJaveid , just use a list. Dictionaries do generally not maintain order, that's the reason we have lists :-)

Comment: @Johannes Weiß It is fine but not accurate, it is adding first value twice then 1 to 10.

Answer (score 0):

In `NSDictionary` **key value pairs matters** not its order in appearence

You can get the value using `objectForKey:` method even if the order is changed