# Sort NSDictionary in ascending order

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, sorting

I am trying to sort an `NSDictionary` in ascending order. I am using this code:

```
NSDictionary *valDict = self.mGetDataDict[key][rowKey];

for (NSString *valueKey in
     [[valDict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)])
{                
    if ([valueKey isEqualToString:@"attr"])
    {
        dictRow = self.mGetDataDict[key][rowKey][valueKey];
    }
    else {
        NSString *valKey = self.mGetDataDict[key][rowKey][valueKey];
        [arrSeatsStatus addObject:valKey];
    }
}
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
1 = off;
10 = off;
2 = on;
3 = on;
4 = on;
5 = on;
6 = on;
7 = on;
8 = on;
9 = on;
```

This is the required output:

```
1: "off",
2: "on",
3: "on",
4: "on",
5: "on",
6: "on",
7: "on",
8: "on",
9: "on",
10: "off"
```

The required output is an actual value coming from JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NSSortDescriptor like this:

```
NSArray* array1 = @[@"1 = off", @"10 = off", @"2 = on", @"3 = on"];
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];

NSLog(@"Ordered array: %@", [array1 sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[ descriptor ]]);
```

which produces this output:

```
2013-06-04 12:26:22.039 EcoverdFira[3693:c07] Ordered array: (
  "1 = off",
  "2 = on",
  "3 = on",
  "10 = off"
)
```

There's a good article on `NSSortedDescriptor`'s [here](http://nshipster.com/nssortdescriptor/).

Comment: How is this marked as a correct answer?? This is not even sorting a Dictionary it just sorting an array!

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is not even the answer of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Get the Array of the Values, sort that array and then get the key corresponding to the value.

You can get the values with:

```
NSArray* values = [myDict allValues];
NSArray* sortedValues = [values sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(comparator)];
```

But, if the collection is as you show in your example, (I mean, you can infer the value from the key), you can always sort the keys instead messing with the values.

Using:

```
NSArray* sortedKeys = [myDict keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(comparator)];
```

The comparator is a message selector which is sent to the object you want to order.

If you want to order strings, then you should use a NSString comparator. The NSString comparators are i.e.: caseInsensitiveCompare or localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:.

If none of these are valid for you, you can call your own comparator function

```
[values sortedArrayUsingFunction:comparatorFunction context:nil]
```

Being comparatorFunction (from [AppleDocumentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSArray))

```
NSInteger intSort(id num1, id num2, void *context)
{
    int v1 = [num1 intValue];
    int v2 = [num2 intValue];
    if (v1 < v2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (v1 > v2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else
        return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this one....

// changes.......

```
NSArray *valDict = [[self.mGetDataDict allValues] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSMutableDictionary *orderedDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (NSString *valor in valDict)
{
    for (NSString *clave in [yourDictionary allKeys])
    {
        if ([valor isEqualToString:[valDict valueForKey:clave]]) 
        {
            [orderedDictionary setValue:valor forKey:clave];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is giving error unrecognized selector sent at instance on very first line.

Comment: That was not the problem, but [dict allKeys] to come rather than values. The issue is even if valor == clave control doesn't go inside.

Comment: you mean you wanna search on the basis of Key ?

Comment: wait i have tried something, just let you know after few mins.

Comment: This thing doesn't sort the keys, yes i need on the basis of key.

Comment: This code doesn't sort the keys and doesn't answers the question.