# Sort NSMutableDictionary keys by Value of type NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have a NSMutableDictionary named `LogDateMsg`. In this dictionary I am storing NSDate objects as values for which the key is of type long.

I need to sort my keys in the descending order based on the date value they have. I am using the below code for that

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"d.M.yyyy kk:mm:ss"];
NSArray *currKeys = [LogDateMsg keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSString* first = (NSString*)a;
    NSString* second = (NSString*)b;
    NSDate* d1=[formatter dateFromString:first];
    NSDate* d2=[formatter dateFromString:second];
    return [d2 compare:d1];
}];
```

But, the above is not giving me the required result.

Is there something wrong with the above code or is there a better way to perform what I want?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ShamasS, I have already seen that answer, but my question is different. It is a NSMutableDictionary which I am trying to sort.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913847/sort-nsdictionary-in-ascending-order

Comment: Can you show a sample date string that you have as key. Also you couldn't be storing long values directly in a dictionary because dictionaries can only hold objects. Long is a primitive type. You must be wrapping it as NSNumber to make it an object first.

Comment: @paranoidcoder, My sample keys are something like this: `Before sort currKeys:(
    1189641421,
    1350490027,
    1102520059,
    1681692777,
    1649760492,
    1967513926,
    1714636915,
    1957747793,
    1804289383,
    2044897763
)`

Comment: @paranoidcoder, and values are: `before sort currvalues:(
    "Mon Dec 14 11:34:15 2015",
    "Mon Dec 14 11:34:15 2015",
    "Mon Dec 14 11:34:14 2015",
    "Mon Dec 14 11:34:14 2015",
    "Mon Dec 14 11:34:16 2015",
    "Mon Dec 14 11:34:16 2015",
    "Mon Dec 14 11:34:14 2015",
    "Mon Dec 14 11:34:15 2015",
    "Mon Dec 14 11:34:14 2015",
    "Mon Dec 14 11:34:15 2015"
)`

Comment: are your values NSDate objects?

Comment: @paranoidcoder, Sorry they are of type NSString. That is why I am converting it to NSString first in the question.

Comment: I think there might be an issue with your date formatting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97818/discussion-between-exception-and-paranoidcoder).

Answer (score -1):

```
NSArray *keys = @[@1189641421, @1350490027, @1102520059, @1681692777];
NSArray *values =  @[@"Mon Dec 14 11:34:10 2015", @"Mon Dec 14 11:34:11 2015", @"Mon Dec 14 11:34:12 2015", @"Mon Dec 14 11:34:13 2015"];
NSMutableDictionary *d = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy"];
currKeys = [d keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSDate *d1 =[formatter dateFromString:(NSString*)a];
    NSDate *d2 =[formatter dateFromString:(NSString*)b];
    return [d2 compare:d1];
}];

NSLog_SM(@"%@", currKeys);
```

Comment: It should be a policy to not downvote without giving a reason in comments otherwise how are we supposed to learn what we are doing wrong. We can keep it anonymous but it should be mandatory to provide a reason.